# When you sign up for a new site, is it supposed to display the favicon/logo of the site in question?

Tags: bug, design, beta-sites, favicon

'cause it doesn't - at least not for beta sites. I just signed up for an account on [Blender.SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) and got the following:

[image]

Rather than using the Blender.SE favicon/logo ([image]), a blank favicon/logo is shown instead. I *did* get a favicon/logo on the corresponding page when signing up for Sharepoint.SE, so I'm guessing this is some sort of bug on the beta sites.